# Can't click links in navbar CSS HTML

Tags: html, css, hyperlink

Not sure if you are allowed to link your website but if it's allowed.
So I can hover all links in the navbar but I can't click them and the pictures of S's is hoverable but not clickable, what am I doing wrong?

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head lang="en">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">

    <title>Nickeb0i Scripts - Landing Page</title>
    <meta property="og:title" content="">

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="fancybox/jquery.fancybox-v=2.1.5.css" type="text/css" media="screen">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">    

    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Titillium+Web:400,600,300,200&subset=latin,latin-ext' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link rel="prefetch" href="images/zoom.png">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="navbar navbar-fixed-top" data-activeslide="1">
        <div class="container">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-responsive-collapse">
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <div class="nav-collapse collapse navbar-responsive-collapse">
                <ul class="nav row">
                    <li data-slide="1" class="col-12 col-sm-2"><a id="menu-link-1"> <span class="icon icon-home"></span> <span class="text">HOME</span></a></li>
                    <li data-slide="2" class="col-12 col-sm-2"><a id="menu-link-2" href="/services"> <span class="icon icon-user"></span> <span class="text">SERVICES</span></a></li>
                    <li data-slide="3" class="col-12 col-sm-2"><a id="menu-link-3" href="/scripts"> <span class="icon icon-briefcase"></span> <span class="text">SCRIPTS</span></a></li></ul>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-2 active-menu"></div>
                </div>
            </div><!-- /.nav-collapse -->
        </div><!-- /.container -->
    </div><!-- /.navbar -->
    <div class="slide story" id="slide-1" data-slide="1">
        <div class="container">
            <div id="home-row-1" class="row clearfix">
                <div class="col-12">
                    <h1 class="font-semibold">NICKEB0I <span class="font-thin">SCRIPTS</span></h1>
                    <br>
                    <br>
                </div><!-- /col-12 -->
            </div><!-- /row -->
            <div id="home-row-2" class="row clearfix">
                <div class="col-12 col-sm-4"><div class="home-hover navigation-slide" data-slide="4"><a href="/scripts"><img src="images/s03.png"></a></div><span>SCRIPTS</span></div>
                <div class="col-12 col-sm-4"><div class="" data-slide="3"></div></div>
                <div class="col-12 col-sm-4"><div class="home-hover navigation-slide" data-slide="5"><a href="/services"><img src="images/s03.png"></a></div><span>SERVICES</span></div>
            </div><!-- /row -->
        </div><!-- /container -->
    </div><!-- /slide1 -->
    <footer>
        <div class="container">
            <p><font color="white">Copyright &copy; Nickeb0i 2016</font><p>
        </div>
    </footer>

</body>
    <script src="js/html5shiv.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.easing.1.3.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="fancybox/jquery.fancybox.pack-v=2.1.5.js"></script>
    <script src="js/script.js"></script>

    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(e) {
        var lis = $('.nav > li');
        menu_focus( lis[0], 1 );

        $(".fancybox").fancybox({
            padding: 10,
            helpers: {
                overlay: {
                    locked: false
                }
            }
        });

    });
    </script>

</html>
```

Comment: You need to show your code on this site. External links to problems will become obsolete and make this question useless in the future.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure about where the error is caused but I'll give you some of the code

Comment: Have a look at [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Do you want all of the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have written `href = "/services"`, add a forward-slash and write `href = "/services/"`. This should work.

Comment: It doesn't work =/ Still same thing, cant click it but I can hover it

Comment: @NiklasErizkn I edited my answer. Are you sure you wrote what I edited it into and not the first answer?

Comment: @NiklasErizkn You need to do it to every single one. Not just services, of course. And remember that your browser might have cached your previous HTML-file. Make sure to delete browser cache if the page is not a local file.

Comment: @NiklasErizkn If you right-click and choose "open in new tab" it works now, so there is some issue with your JavaScript probably.

This seems to be the issue: `var offset_top = ( dataslide == 1 ) ? '0px' : $('.slide[data-slide="' + dataslide + '"]').offset().top;`

Comment: Ye I know it works when you rightclick it, hmmm Should I remove it?

Comment: @NiklasErizkn Whether you remove it or fix it is your decision, but there is where your problem lies. John M pointed this out already.

Comment: I did remove it, I can't believe it still isnt working?

Comment: @NiklasErizkn You did not remove it as far as I can tell.

Comment: Are you sure? I removed it from script.js

Comment: @NiklasErizkn You did not. It is the 187th row. Perhaps you forgot to upload the new script.js.

Comment: I found this
 links.click(function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  dataslide = $(this).attr('data-slide');
  goToByScroll(dataslide);
  $(".nav-collapse").collapse('hide');
 });

Comment: I removed it and can now click the links in the navbar but not on the body

Comment: @NiklasErizkn You have an undefined method called `goToByScroll();` on line 191.

Comment: That should be removed

Comment: @NiklasErizkn Overall, you have a lot of weird JavaScript that you probably do not understand yourself. I suggest not copy-pasting other people's JavaScript but actually doing things yourself. I do not know the issue this time, but it has probably something to do with your scripts.js.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure that this is related to it but if I click a button my console immediately shows an error:

```
script.js:187 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'top' of undefined
```

Answer (score 0):

You're getting this error
`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'top' of undefined`

Because you're trying to select a DOM object that doesn't exist:

`var offset_top = ( dataslide == 1 ) ? '0px' : $('.slide[data-slide="' + dataslide + '"]').offset().top;`

Adding the class `slide` to your elements with data-slide attributes stops the error.

But you should ask yourself, do you really need javascript like this for navigation and hover effects?

Comment: I'm using a bootstrap so I guess there is unneeded stuff in it :)